# How can I find the gradient of a non linear SVM wrt input?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, subgradient

Given that an SVM will have the following function:
[image]

And if I was to use a kernel, this would become:

[image]

Where the kernel can be the Gaussian kernel:

[image]

How Would I go about finding its gradient wrt the input? I need to know this as to then apply this to a larger problem of a CNN with its last layer being this SVM, so I can then find the gradient of this output wrt the input of the CNN.

Comment: found some work done on this here: ecmlpkdd2013.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/527.pdf They talk about something similar in Section 3.1. Does it hold any weight with what I want to do?

Comment: A lot of chain rule. Is there a particular part that’s giving you trouble? Are you comfortable with the multivariable chain rule? Note also that there will be values where it is non-differentiable, because of the max.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would you be able to expand on your point about the max not being differentiable at some points please? 
The chain rule itself is a bit difficult for me, would you be able to expand or give me a direction with this also?

Comment: Mastering the multivariable chain rule takes a while. I'm afraid I don't have time right now to make this problem an extended teaching example for that rule. The max function is not differentiable at zero. I'll try to think of a good text reference for multi-variable calculus. Best of luck